# URL Req query seach in mongoose with Query filters

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

This is the API URL (Numbers in URL like 1,2,3,4.... suppose them as mongoose _id)
https://localhost:8000/api/getAllAstrologers?category=1,2,5&skills=6,3,9&languages=&specilization=8&name=manoj&orderby=ASC

How can I run the my .find code with all these query I recieve . Sometimes I may or may not get all these query.

```
name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
},
languages: [{
    astolLang_id: {
        type: String,
    },
    name: {
        type: String
    }
}],
specilization: [{
    astolSpec_id: {
        type: String,
    },
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    specilizationImage:{
        type:String
    }
}],
category: [{
    astolCat_id: {
        type: String,
    },
    name: {
        type: String
    }
}],
skills: [{
    astolSkill_id: {
        type: String,
    },
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    skillImage:{
        type:String
    }
}],
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
 .find({$or:[{ category: {$in: arrayOfCategories}, skills: {$in: arrayOfSkill}]}
```

You can try working with $contains too.

Comment: So first How can I get the url queries stored into variable or array. Can you help with that too?

Comment: if you are getting a string you can use .split() to create an array out of it

Comment: var arrayOfCategories = [ '6309bbaf78052b1f1a094651' , '6309bbaf78052b1f1a094652']
    var arrayOfSkill = ['6309bbaf78052b1f1a094653']
    const astro = Astrologer.find({ category : {$in: arrayOfCategories}, skills: {$in: arrayOfSkill}})           I used this code but I got this error 'TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON'

Comment: Try .find({$or:[{ category: : {$in: arrayOfCategories}, skills: {$in: arrayOfSkill}]}

Comment: Play with the operators: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/

Comment: Remember to close accept the answer if it fixed you problem.

Comment: This answer partially help me btw thanks bro.